# Cleaning timeseries data and Standardizing the sample rate in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a timeseries data and I would like to clean the data by approximating the missing data points and standardizing the sample rate.

Given the fact that there might be some unevenly spaced datapoints, I would like to define a function to get the timeseries and an interval X (e.g., 30 minutes or any other interval) as an input and gives the timeseries with points being spaced within X intervals as an output.

As you can see below, the periods are every 10 minutes but some data points are missing. So the algorithm should detect the missing times and remove them and create the appropriate times and generate the value for them. Then based on the defined function, the sample rate should be changed and standardized.
For approximating missing data and cleaning it, either average or linear interpolation would work.

Here is a part of raw data:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({

    "Time": ["10:09:00","10:19:00","10:29:00","10:43:00","10:59:00 ", "11:09:00"],
    "Value": ["378","378","379","377","376", "377"],
    
})

df
```

Comment: You forgot a digit in the first timestamp and you also have some trailing whitespace that you need to get rid of before anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to convert `"Time""` into a **datetime index**. Make pandas recognize the dates as actual dates with `df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])`. Then Set time as the index: `df = df.set_index("Time")`.

Once you have the datetime index, you can do all sorts of time-based operations with it. In your case, you want to **resample**: `df.resample('10T')`

This leaves us with the following code:

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%H:%S:%M")
df = df.set_index("Time")

df.resample('10T')
```

From here on you have a lot of options on how to treat cases in which you have missing data (fill / interpolate / ...), or in which you have multiple data points for one new one (average / sum / ...). I suggest you take a look at [the pandas resampling api](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample). For conversions and formatting between `string` and `datetime` refer to [strftime](https://strftime.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I had converted "Time" column to datetime index. My main question is how to fill/interpolate the NaN values and after that how to define a new resampling rate (e.g., 144 minutes) and a function that would return the "values" in each day (given the data is collected every 10 minutes... so each 144 points will in turn represent data collected within a day). I would like to define a custom function that gets inputs and returns required outputs.

Comment: This depends on *how* specifically you want to interpolate and aggregate. For a sampling frequency of 10 mins, with means for multiple datapoints and linear interpolation for missing ones, for example, you can use `df.resample('10T').mean().interpolate('linear')`. For daily means just use `df.resample('1D').mean()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot... just another quick question... why would you think df.resample('10T'). interpolate('linear') does not work and give the error "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"... I mean how is "df.resample('10T').mean().interpolate('linear')" different from "df.resample('10T'). interpolate('linear')" from the mathematical point of view?

Comment: Before using `.interpolate` (which fills in the NaN values), you have to decide how to proceed for cases in which you have multiple values for one timestamp (kind of like `.groupby.aggregate()`).  The `.mean()` function tells the resampler to use the mean in these cases and returns a normal dataframe.